# SQL Query on join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables mem_loan and shares. In mem_loan table i have a column called DATE and in shares i have a column named noofshares. No the primary key of mem_loan is a foreign key in shares table. I want to use the following query but getting a error.

```
SELECT SUM(noofshares),year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) 
FROM shares s,mem_loan ml 
JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno = shares.loan_acno 
WHERE year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate())
```

and the error is as follws :

> Column 'mem_loan.DOS' is invalid in the select list 
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function 
>   or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help me out

Comment: i wwant the sum function to be used as i want to get the sum of noofshares

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message says, you need to GROUP BY the columns that aren't contained in aggregate functions.

However your example SQL also appears to have other errors. In particular, you have included the `mem_loan` table twice but only one join condition so a cross join will be performed. It is unlikely that this is what you mean.

Comment: but i also want where clause as i have a condition of checking the year

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT SUM(noofshares),year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) 
FROM shares s,mem_loan ml JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno=shares.loan_acno 
where year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate()) 
group by year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105))
```

Comment: @NimishKulkarni: Sure? I'm pretty sure that that this doesn't work. If it runs without errors (which I doubt) it will still give you the wrong result. As I said, you need to reconsider your joins.

Comment: yup, I didn't even see the double-jointed query. Should be this: SELECT SUM(noofshares),year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) 
FROM shares s
JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno=shares.loan_acno 
where year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate()) 
group by year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(noofshares),
  year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) 
FROM 
  shares s,mem_loan ml 
  JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno=shares.loan_acno 
where year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate())
GROUP BY year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105))
```

Or you can do like this:

```
SELECT
    t.noofshares,
    SUM(t.LoanYear)
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
          noofshares,
          year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) as LoanYear
        FROM 
          shares s,mem_loan ml 
          JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno=shares.loan_acno 

    ) AS t
where 
    t.LoanYear=year(getdate())
GROUP BY
    t.LoanYear
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

```
GROUP BY year(convert(datetime,dos,105))
```

for your aggregate SUM() to work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to aggregate using the Sum function and sql server doesn't know which year record to use from the mem_loan table.

For starters choose you aggregate function for year (ie. MIN):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(noofshares),
    MIN(year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105))) 
FROM
    shares s,
    mem_loan ml 
JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno=shares.loan_acno 
WHERE 
    year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OVER` to get around having to include the column `dos` as part of your aggregate.
Disclaimer: I haven't got management studio with me to test:

```
   SELECT SUM(noofshares) OVER (PARTITION BY year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) ),year(convert(datetime,mem_loan.dos,105)) 
FROM shares s,mem_loan ml 
JOIN mem_loan ON mem_loan.loan_acno = shares.loan_acno 
WHERE year(convert(datetime,dos,105))=year(getdate())
```

More information on `OVER`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx